# Can I use the Telosys wizard without installing Eclipse?

Tags: telosys

I am trying to learn telosys. The eclipse demo seems great.
However, I tried to install the plugin for VSCode, and it did not add any option/menu item anywhere in the VSCode editor.

The eclipse demo shows a great wizard based interface. Is there any way to get that interface without having to install eclipse.

Also, in case it is not possible, which package of eclipse do I need to install to optimally use telosys? I wanted to try out the python & angular bundles of telosys.

Answer (score 0):

Yes indeed, the **Telosys VS Code plugin** provides only **syntax coloration** for Telosys files edition (".entity" files for example). Thus there's no particular changes in the VSCode menu.
VSCode is just one code editor (among others) that you can use with Telosys-CLI. The editors extensions are just provided to be more confortable when you're editing Telosys files. All the code generation is supposed to be launch from the command line in Telosys-CLI.

If you want a fully integrated tool, **Eclipse + Telosys plugin** is the best solution. Telosys Eclipse plugin is installable with all Eclipse versions, so you can choose one of these Eclipse packages :
https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/
for example "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers" and use "Eclipse Marketplace" to install :

- **Telosys plugin**
  https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/telosys-code-generator-java-javascript-python-nodejs-php-c-javaee-spring-jax-rs-vuejs
- **Python plugin**
  https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/pydev-python-ide-eclipse